# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in PDF component

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am getting following error , see below: what i am doing wrong?

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Object.createModels (vendor.js:117599)
    at Object.jsPDF.API.autoTable (vendor.js:116203)
    at PDFComponent.push../src/app/Shared/Directives/Download/pdf-generator.component.ts.PDFComponent.downloadPDF (main.js:344)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/PDFComponent.ngfactory.js:13)
    at handleEvent (vendor.js:74287)
    at callWithDebugContext (vendor.js:75796)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (vendor.js:75383)
    at dispatchEvent (vendor.js:70702)
    at vendor.js:71327
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (vendor.js:95474)
```

Code below

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output,Inject  } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AuthService} from '../../Services/auth.service';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';

declare var jsPDF: any; // Important
@Component({
    selector: 'pdf-download',
    templateUrl: './pdf-generator.component.html',

})
export class PDFComponent   {
    @Input() downloadData: any; 
    //@Input() columns: any; 
    @Input() columns: any[] = []; 
    @Input() reportName: string; 
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }
    // public columns=[];


    downloadPDF(){


 for(var key in  this.downloadData[0])
         {

            this.columns.push({title:key,dataKey:key})
        }
}
```

Comment: The error seems to be thrown in the jsPDF `autoTable` constructor. Where are you calling / initializing it? The error, to me, is likely related to this constructor specifically: https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/src/main.ts#L16

Comment: I think, you need to check if the `this.downloadData` is available then only allow the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a problem how you are doing for each loop try to use following Object Array. it may help you

for example:

```js
var downloadData=[{item:1,value:"one"},{item:2,value:"two"},{item:3,value:"three"}]

  var   columns=[]
     for(var key in  downloadData)
             {
    
                columns.push({title:downloadData[key].item,dataKey:downloadData[key].value})
            }
            
            console.log(columns)
```